# Kafka mirror maker duplicates when DCs are isolated

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 5 kafka 1.0.0 clusters:

- 4 of them are made of 3 nodes and are in different regions in the world
- the last one is made of 5 nodes and is an aggregate only cluster.

We are using MirrorMaker (later referenced as MM) to read from the regional clusters and copy the data in the aggregate cluster in our HQ datacenter.

And not sure about where to run it we have currently 2 cases in our prod environment:

- MM in the region: reading locally and pushing to aggregate cluster in remote data-center (DC), before committing offsets locally. I tend to call this the push mode (pushing the data)
- MM in the DC of the aggregate cluster: reading remotely the data, writing it locally before committing the offsets on remote DC.

What happened is that we got the entire DC where we have our aggregate server totally isolated from a network point of view. And in both cases, we got duplicated records in our aggregate cluster.

## Push mode = MM local to the regional cluster, pushing data to remote aggregate cluster

MM started to throw errors like this:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 674364 on topic-partition <topic>-4, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

then:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

which is ok so far because of idempotence.

But finally we got errors like:

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic debug_sip_callback-delivery with key: null, value: 1640 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for <topic>-4: 30032 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
ERROR Error when sending message to topic <topic> with key: null, value: 1242 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Producer is closed forcefully.
```

causing MM to stop and I think this is the problem causing duplicates (I need to dig the code, but could be that it lost information about idempotence and on restart it resumed from previously committed offsets).

## Pull mode = MM local to the aggregate cluster, pulling data from remote regional cluster

MM instances (with logs at INFO level in this case) started seeing the broker as dead:

```
INFO [Consumer clientId=mirror-maker-region1-agg-0, groupId=mirror-maker-region1-agg] Marking the coordinator kafka1.region1.internal:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
```

At the same time on the broker side, we got:

```
INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member mirror-maker-region1-agg-0-de2af312-befb-4af7-b7b0-908ca8ecb0ed in group mirror-maker-region1-agg has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
...
INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Group mirror-maker-region1-agg with generation 42 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-2) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Later on MM side, a lot of:

```
WARN [Consumer clientId=mirror-maker-region1-agg-0, groupId=mirror-maker-region1-agg] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

and finally when network came back:

```
ERROR [Consumer clientId=mirror-maker-region1-agg-0, groupId=mirror-maker-region1-agg] Offset commit failed on partition <topic>-dr-8 at offset 382424879: The coordinator is not aware of this member. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

i.e., it could not commit in region1 the offsets written on agg because of the rebalancing. And it resumed after rebalance from previously successfully committed offset causing duplicates.

## Configuration

Our MM instances are configured like this:

For our consumer:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1.region1.intenal:9092,kafka2.region1.internal:9092,kafka3.region1.internal:9092
group.id=mirror-maker-region-agg
auto.offset.reset=earliest
isolation.level=read_committed
```

For our producer:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1.agg.internal:9092,kafka2.agg.internal:9092,kafka3.agg.internal:9092,kafka4.agg.internal:9092,kafka5.agg.internal:9092
compression.type=none
request.timeout.ms=30000
max.block.ms=60000
linger.ms=15000
max.request.size=1048576
batch.size=32768
buffer.memory=134217728
retries=2147483647
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
acks=all
enable.idempotence=true
```

Any idea how we can get the "only once" delivery on top of exactly once in case of 30 min isolated DCs?

Comment: Specially wondering if there shouldn't be options:
-1- in pull mode, to delay the rebalance of consumers and not do it if within that delay all consumers from group are gone. And then when they come back, give them some time to all come back before triggering a rebalance. In that case, after 30 min when network comes back, the consumer can commit their offsets and we do not have duplicates;
-2- in pull mode, to have MirrorMaker to commit offsets on target aggregate cluster (like best practice of storing offset of consumer together with data consumed, in a transaction manner).